# Create dynamically a layout

Tags: android, layout, dynamic

I am trying to create a layout dynamically. 
I am getting data from a database and and using it to define the layout.
Every row from the database should be  displayed in the layout.

I don't want to use a  ListView because my next step is to click at the layout and show some details.

Here is my code to create the dynamic layout:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutausgabe,null);

        // insert into main view
        View insertPoint = findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        ((ViewGroup) insertPoint).addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Here is the layout, which should be inserted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Abfahrt - Ankunft |"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text=" Dauer |"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text=" Umstieg |"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text=" Route"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the place ( Scrollview ) where the layout should be inserted:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" >


    </ScrollView>
```

thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: you need to put any layout like linear or relative because , scrollview doesn't accept more than one child , so making linear layout and add your child  linear then add the linear to scroll view

Comment: Wonderful! Now, what's the question?

Comment: You should reconsider your choice not to use a ListView.  The listview lets you click on an item and take action.

Comment: what do you mean?
should i insert a linearlayout into my scroll view?

Comment: Yeah i know this with the listview but i dont wanna have a structure like one row under the next row. I wanna have a structured activity with some main facts and by klicking on the Activity showing some details in the SubActivity

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
View insertPoint = findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutausgabe,insertPoint, false);

((ViewGroup) insertPoint).addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Comment: That didn's work because there is something wrong with the inflater.inflate(...)

Comment: Instead of View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutausgabe,insertPoint, false); try what you had :         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutausgabe,null);

Answer (score 0):

the ScrollView only takes one child , so you cant add many childs to it ,

to solve this you should put a LinearLayout with orientation set to verticatl inside the ScrollView , and then add your views to the LinearLayout .

Hope that helps